# CSS - Background image

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am not sure how to change the background of an image tag in css. For example, I have a darker background in my webpage. Let's say I include an image of a purple X with a white background. How would I change the background of that purple X image to be the same color as my body.

Comment: Images don't have CSS backgrounds.   If your image is a partially transparent GIF or PNG, you can set the background color on the DOM element that contains the image.

Comment: If the image file has a white background by itself it will be hard to change it with CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add `mix-blend-mode: multiply;` to your `<img>`'s css. It will render the white 'transparent' but it'll also alter the other colors in the image.
Best solution would probably be to use transparent PNGs.